# Почему дублируются комментарии + как реализовать проверку GET запроса?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, request

Такая проблема, что при обновлении страницы, дублируется последний оставленный комментарий(заносится в бд и снова выводится на экран). Как это исправить? Прошу Вас написать код, и куда вставить его. Я даже удалил POST переменную, но ничего не выходит. Что уже только не пробовал. СМОТРЕТЬ КОД ФОРМЫ И ПОСЛЕ НЕЕ.

```
<?php 
    require_once('sqlconnect.php');
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE id = :id DESC';
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(['id'=> $id]);
    $news_id = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if ($id > $news_id->id){
        header('Location: error.php');
    }
?>





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>

    <?php
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = :id';
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(['id'=> $id]);
            $article = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $website_title = "$article->title";
    require "blocks/head.php" ?>

</head>
<body>
    <? require "blocks/header.php" ?>



<main class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1><?=$article->title?></h1>
                    <p><b>Автор статьи: </b><mark><?=$article->autor?></p></mark>
                    <?php
                        $date = date("d ", $article->date);
                        $array= [
                            "января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня", "июля", "августа","сентября","октября", "ноября", "декабря"
                        ];
                        $date .= $array[date('n', $article->date) - 1];
                        $date .= date(' H:i', $article->date);
                    ?>
                <p><b>Время публикации: </b><u><?=$date?></p></u>
                <p>
                    <?=$article->intro?>
                    <br><br>
                    <?=$article->text?>
                </p>
            </div>  

            <h3 class="mt-5">Комментарии</h3>

            <form action="news.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>" method="POST">

                <label>Сообщение</label>
                <textarea type="text" name="message" class="form-control col-md-6" id="message"></textarea>

                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-2 mb-4" name="mess_send"id="mess_send" value="Добавть комментарий">
            </form>




            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['mess_send']) && $_POST['message']!='' && isset($_COOKIE['log'])){
                    $commentator = trim(filter_var($_COOKIE['log'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
                    $mess = trim(filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

                    $sql = 'INSERT INTO comms(username, message, article_id) VALUES(?,?,?)';
                    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $query->execute([$commentator, $mess, $_GET['id']]);

                    unset($_POST['message']);


                }


                $sql = 'SELECT username, message FROM `comms` WHERE `article_id` = :id ORDER BY `id`';
                $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute(['id' => $_GET['id']]);
                $comments = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                foreach ($comments as $comment) {
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-info mb-4'>
                            <h4>$comment->username</h4>
                            <p>$comment->message</p>
                        </div>";
                }


            ?>



        </div>
        <? require "blocks/aside.php" ?>
    </div>
</main>


<? require "blocks/footer.php" ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Второе, что я не могу сделать, так это проверку GET запроса в URL-e. ЕСЛИ id ПОСТА В URL-e БОЛЬШЕ ЧЕМ id ПОСЛЕДНЕГО ПОСТА, ТО ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАГОЛОВОК НА СТРАНИЦУ 404. Как реализовать?(Я написал как думаю, вначале предыдущего кода перед html). Но если я захожу на любой пост, то всегда 404 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"при обновлении страницы, дублируется последний оставленный комментарий" - это происходит потому, что вы повторяете POST запрос - еще раз посылаете данные формы. Решение - после добавления комментария на страниц сделать редирект на страницу. Тогда при нажатии F5 не будет заново происходить POST запрос.

```
if(isset($_POST['mess_send']) && $_POST['message']!='' && isset($_COOKIE['log'])){
    ....
    // в конец добавляем редирект
    header("Location: 'урл страницы'"); 
    exit();
}
```

По поводу второго вопроса

```
$news_id = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

на самом деле возвращает не id, а объект с данными, если такая запись есть в бд или же false, если такой записи нет. Так что

```
$news = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if ($news === false) {
    // тут 404 ошибка
```

Comment: Но я не могу выслать header, нужно до html это делать. Может, есть способ без переадресации это сделать? Как, например на ютубе, тостере или вк

Comment: можно через javascript; echo "<script>location = 'урл страницы';</script>"; вместо хедера

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но со вторым вопросом не разберусь. Написал все также, но при вызове var_dump($news_id); всегда выводится "bool(false)" как на существующей странице, так и на несуществующей

Comment: 1й и 2й запрос одинаковы, так что можно оставить только 1й. Только в 1м у вас ошибка "$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE id = :id DESC';" а надо как ниже "$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE id = :id ;" без бесхозного DESC . Похоже вы отключили вывод ошибок и мучаетесь.

Comment: Вывод ошибок? у меня текстовый редактор, а не компилятор, а если вы про ошибки в браузере, то они включены

Comment: Убрал desc и все заработало :) Спасбо!